# Select a distinct RowId based on series of trainnumbers

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a excel(2010) sheet with data like this:

```
trainnumber RowId
2           0
2           1
2           3
4           4
4           5
4           6
```

And I want a list like this:

```
RowId
0
4
```

Meaning the first RowId of each of the trainnumber series

I've tried build a SELECT statement, but in doesn't work.(I suck at SQL lol)

```
sSQL = "select " & _
              "RowId, " & _
              "(select top 1 trainnumber from @t t2 where t.RowId = t2.RowId order by RowId), " & _
              "from @t t " & _
              "group by RowId"
```

It tells me, that there's an Syntax Error in the subselect, so I tried the used the sheetname, but it gives me the same error:

```
sSQL = "select " & _
              "RowId, " & _
              "(select top 1 trainnumber from @[Conversion$] t2 where t.RowId = t2.RowId order by RowId), " & _
              "from @[Conversion$] t " & _
              "group by RowId"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want first for each , you can get the `min`:

```
Select min(rowID)
from youtable
group by trainer_number
;
```

Comment: @ If you need a `VBA` Please give a bit mroe samples, e.g. at least 3 different `trainer_numbers`.. so we can see the data pattern.. :)