# How to make a list of PrimaryRowId and Matching RowIds

Tags: sql, excel, vba

In my previous question ([Select a distinct RowId based on series of trainnumbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629325/select-a-distinct-rowid-based-on-series-of-trainnumbers)) I got a nice list of RowIds.

Now I'd like to make that list complete and totally awesome! :)

My raw data(Excel 2010) looks like this:

```
Time    Wagons     Delete     DayType    Plate    trainnumber   RowId
05.28    1                       1      0901-046     2          38676
08.20    2                       1      0901-003     2          18676
05.25    2            x          1      0901-046     2          28676
15.28    2                       1      0901-046     2          3676
23.20    3                       1      0601-001     2          3867
05.08    3                       1      0901-046     2          3876
00.28    L            x          1      0901-046     2          8676
00.00                            1      0901-046     2          367
```

I need a list that groups the Primary RowIds(the list from the previous question) with the RowIds that match it by the following criteria:

- on the Primary and Matching rows the following must be the SAME:

  - trainnumber
  - DayType
  - Time
- on the Primary and Matching rows the Plate must be DIFFERENT
- Wagons must be MORE THAN 1 (The column contains rows with numbers, letters and nothing)
- Delete must be empty

When matches are found, I need the RowId of the match.

Ideally a dataset like this:

```
PrimaryRowId    Match#1    Match#2    Match#3    Match#4
15674            5465        456       5456        45656
5564             231         132       1321        7862
```

It's possible that there's more matches per Primary RowId, but that's ok.

My SQL skills is somewhat limited, so that's why I'm asking you guys. :)

I *think* it might be something like this:

```
SELECT RowId
FROM Conversion
WHERE trainnumber=trainnumber and daytype=daytype and 
      time=time and plate<>plate and Wagons>1 and delete="" 
GROUP BY RowId
```

But it would only give me one(1) RowId at a time. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris,

To use SQL to match items like this, you need to tell SQL to find the matches in a pair of tables (actually two copies of the same table). This is known as a self join.

```
SELECT A.Time,
       A.TrainNumber,
       A.DayType,
       MIN(A.Rowid) AS Master
FROM CONVERSION AS A
INNER JOIN CONVERSION AS B ON A.TrainNumber=B.TrainNumber
AND A.DayType=B.DayType
AND A.Time=B.Time
WHERE A.Wagons>"1"
  AND B.Wagons>"1"
  AND A.Plate<>B.Plate
  AND A.Delete IS NULL
  AND B.Delete IS NULL
GROUP BY A.Time,
         A.TrainNumber,
         A.DayType;
```

The two copies of Conversion are given the aliases A and B.

On the INNER JOIN line, we specify the fields which have to match.

On the WHERE line, we specify the fields which have to be different, as well as the other conditions (which must be specified for both A and B).

The first column gives the lowest row ID for each matching train, and the second column the other matching row IDs.

Now we have a list of master rows, we can join this again to Conversion to produce a list of slave rows :

```
SELECT D.Master,
       C.Rowid
FROM CONVERSION AS C
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT A.Time,
          A.TrainNumber,
          A.DayType,
          MIN(A.Rowid) AS Master
   FROM CONVERSION AS A
   INNER JOIN CONVERSION AS B ON A.TrainNumber=B.TrainNumber
   AND A.DayType=B.DayType
   AND A.Time=B.Time
   WHERE A.Wagons>"1"
     AND B.Wagons>"1"
     AND A.Plate<>B.Plate
     AND A.Delete IS NULL
     AND B.Delete IS NULL
   GROUP BY A.Time,
            A.TrainNumber,
            A.DayType) AS D ON C.TrainNumber=D.TrainNumber
AND C.DayType=D.DayType
AND C.Time=D.Time
WHERE C.Delete IS NULL
  AND D.Master<C.Rowid
ORDER BY D.Master,
         C.Rowid;
```

I've tested this with a little extra test data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db82f/16)

Comment: That looks awesome. :) But I'm getting the output in one column. I can't see how I can get it like I've shown in my question. :-/ Can you?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it will look even more awesome!
If I were doing, this, I would normalise the data to have a list of unique trains having more than one non-deleted wagon (in a way, that's what my query is doing).
Then I could produce a list of plates for each train.
Of course, it depends what you want as the final result.

Comment: Hehe, great! :D The problem is that it's a excel sheet and the data will be modified a lot and many times, so normalization isn't really an option I have currently. :-/ What I want, is what I first asked and what I elaborated on in my last comment. :) I need this list in order to do some (you guessed it) modifications to the rows and other stuff. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait (im-?)patiently. ;P

Comment: Lol, I've just noticed that you've updated your answer. :D First impressing is AWESOME!! But then I looked at it again. ;P The Delete has to be empty, not full. ;) When I change it to either `A.Delete="" AND B.Delete=""` or `A.Delete<>"X" AND B.Delete<>"X"` I get 0 rows! :O What gives??

Comment: I've spotted another little problem. Your Wagons field is not numeric. If letters are treated as greater than 1, you can compare the field to '1'. Otherwise I need to know what sort of database you're using to make sure I get the conversion right.

Comment: I can't test it right now, as I'm not at work, but I can tell you, that I'm not actually using a database - I'm using MS Excel 2010... :) I have edited the Wagons field, and I _think_ that part works. ;D The Conversion "table" is actually an excel sheet, so I'm not sure if I have Null values, but I'll find out tomorrow. :D

Comment: ...and now I have tested it, and surprise! IS NULL works! Yay! :D After a quick look at the result I think it's correct, but I need by boss to check it to be 100 % sure. :)

Comment: Excellent. IS NULL is the usual way to test for empty in SQL, but I wasn't sure with it being Excel that there might have been an empty string or a space.

Comment: Hmm..I've looked closer at the results, and found something a bit troublesome. A Match with, say, 3 matches are repeated later on, but by using match#1 as the primary row and therefore with one less match - and later still, a row with match#2 as primary and only one match(being the same as #3 on first occurrence, #2 on the second). Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: I'm wondering if a subselect that gets the Primary RowIds could be a nice solution?

Comment: Chat not available because *you* need 20 points to chat. Re primary row IDs, what is primary ? If you can say that wagon 1 always exists in the 'interesting' trains then OK. It's more difficult to get what you want for your report in SQL compared with VBA, but it would take **me** longer to do this in VBA.

Comment: Oh, I guess I'm too noobish. ;) The Primary Row is the First Row in a series of trainnumbers of defined by my other question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629325/select-a-distinct-rowid-based-on-series-of-trainnumbers) Wagons define how many wagons a train has and thus cannot be used as an identifier. Actually it's not for a report, but "just" a needed list to make my code a **lot** shorter and easier to maintain. :)

Comment: Wow, now THAT looks really awesome! :D Can't wait to try it out on monday - I don't work fridays. ;)

Comment: Mind=Blown! It works! Yay! :D I had to change the Wagons column to a number-only column, but other than that, no problems - so far. Boss approval is waiting... :) :)

Comment: I will - as soon as it's boss-approved. :) I really like the way you explain your answer - do you work as a teacher or something? :)

Comment: I try hard to give a good explanation. My parents were teachers, so that helps. I'm also used to working internationally.

Comment: Well, it seams to be working alright. Your answer has been marked as correct. :) Thanks again for your awesome help! :) :)